# How to listen to incoming HDP connection Android bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth, serial-port

In the Bluetooth HDP sample by Google, it seems it only try to initiate connections to the device (so that the phone would be the client and the health device would be the server).

However, the health device that I have (Omron 708-BT) is only designed to be a Bluetooth client but not a server - it can only initiate connections but it can't listen to incoming connections.

How can I make my phone listen for incoming HDP connections similar to how it's done for SPP [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ConnectingAsAServer)?

Answer (score 1):

There is a sample app based on Antidote 11073 stack that does exactly that:

https://github.com/brasileiroaraujo/HealthServiceAndroid

Basically you need to register a Handler in BluetoothHDPService (by sending a MSG_REG_CLIENT). In the example source, handler name is mIncomingHandler.

The handler gets messages like BluetoothHDPService.STATUS_CREATE_CHANNEL, when a device connects and creates a HDP channel.

Don't forget to register the data types you accept by sending BluetoothHDPService.MSG_REG_HEALTH_APP messages. Data type for blood pressure is 0x1007, I think.